# How to deploy RESTful api created with node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, web-hosting

I have few questions that I don't understand or need a few tips.
Two weeks ago i started with angularJS and created few app's, than I started with RESTful api's and than went to node JS to make one RESTful api.But now i am bit confused...I have made node js api that connects to mySQL and can handle PUT, GET, DELETE and POST and when i use Postman, it works smooth. Now i want to set my node js RESTful api on some hosting so it can be available 24/7 and i am not sure how to do it... do i need tome kind of cloud service or normal web hosting can serve it? As i see, it must run server side and not sure how to implement it :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

- you could use "standard" web hosting, as long as you have ssh access to the box, and not just FTP. This usually means a dedicated server, a VM (often known as a VPS), or some times of shared servers, but that's rarely the case. Basically, if it's free or very very cheap, it probably won't do.
- or you could use hosting services that are specifically tailored for node.js apps (and a few others), such as Red Hat's OpenShift, Heroku, and others.

Comment: ok I see the picture now :-). I will use my web hosting for my angular js api and RESTful api will be hosted on a specific server for node js applications like you mentioned before. Thanks for clearing it!